# Add new column with name of each element as a value

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have a bunch of dataframes in a list. I'm trying to add a new column to each dataframe with the 'name' of the dataframes as a value.

My example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_2018 <- data_frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3),
                      y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
df_2017 <- data_frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1),
                      y2 = c(6, 5, 4))

list <- list(df_2017 = df_2017, df_2018 = df_2018)
```

results in:

```
> list
$df_2017
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     y1    y2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     6
2     2     5
3     1     4

$df_2018
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     y1    y2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4
2     2     5
3     3     6
```

Desired outcome:

```
> list
$df_2017
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     y1    y2 year   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1     3     6 df_2017
2     2     5 df_2017
3     1     4 df_2017

$df_2018
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     y1    y2 year   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1     1     4 df_2018
2     2     5 df_2018
3     3     6 df_2018
```

I'm learning `purrr`'s `map()` functions, so if you can show an answer with purrr, extra points!

I'm thinking abt the following, but that doesn't work:

```
map(list,
    add_column,
    ~ year = names(.x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `map2` and `mutate` to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mlist <- list(df_2017 = df_2017, df_2018 = df_2018)

map2(mlist, names(mlist), ~ mutate(.x, year = .y)) 

$df_2017
  y1 y2    year
1  3  6 df_2017
2  2  5 df_2017
3  1  4 df_2017

$df_2018
  y1 y2    year
1  1  4 df_2018
2  2  5 df_2018
3  3  6 df_2018
```

Comment: Or a little shorter: `imap(list, ~ mutate(.x, year = .y))`

Answer (score 1):

tidyverse solution :-)

We take the list and the names of the list, use `map2` from purrr and `add_column` from tibble to bring everything together.

```
map2(list, names(list), function(x, y) add_column(x, year = y))

$`df_2017`
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     y1    y2 year   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1     3     6 df_2017
2     2     5 df_2017
3     1     4 df_2017

$df_2018
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     y1    y2 year   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1     1     4 df_2018
2     2     5 df_2018
3     3     6 df_2018
```

Comment: Or a little shorter: `imap(list, ~ add_column(.x, year = .y))`

Answer (score 1):

`base` solution using `lapply`

```
lst <- list(df_2017 = df_2017, df_2018 = df_2018) #I'm using lst as name instead of "list" as it is reserved in R
temp <- lapply(seq_along(lst), function(x) rep(names(lst[x]), times = nrow(lst[[x]])))
lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) cbind(lst[[i]], year=temp[[i]]))
#returns
[[1]]
  y1 y2    year
1  3  6 df_2017
2  2  5 df_2017
3  1  4 df_2017

[[2]]
  y1 y2    year
1  1  4 df_2018
2  2  5 df_2018
3  3  6 df_2018
```

Following @markus, here another option using `Map`

```
Map("[<-", lst, "year", value = names(lst))
```

Comment: Try `Map("[<-", list, "year", value = names(list))`

Comment: Elegant @markus! I include in the answer citing you.